# Code for codergopher

Tags: python-3.x

I don't know what is wrong. I was doing the same as you on video. My code looks like:

```
import pygame
import time
import sys
from pygame import *

WIN_HEIGHT = 500
WIN_WIDTH = 500
red = (255,0,0)
green = (0,255,0)

DISPLAY = (WIN_WIDTH, WIN_HEIGHT)

DEPTH = 32
TIMER = pygame.time.Clock()
FLAGS = 0

pygame.init()

screen = pygame.display.set_mode(DISPLAY, DEPTH, FLAGS)


def main():

  playerObject = playerClass(0, 0)
  while 1==1:

    TIMER.tick(60)
    playerObject.update()
    screen.fill(red)

    pygame.display.update()

class entity(pygame.sprite.Sprite):
  def __init__(self):
    pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)


class playerClass(entity):
  def __init__(self,x,y):
    self.xvel = 0
    self.yvel = 0
    self.image = Surface((32,32))
    self.image.fill(Color('#00FF32'))
    self.image.convert()
    self.rect = Rect(x, y, 32, 32)
  def update():
    pass


main()
```

If you want to know more, just ask. I really want to lern pygame in practic. Your videos are so helpfull and if you will fix my code, I'll hit a like ;)

Comment: Who is you? I am not. SO is no platform to adress certain ppl from the community. Please go over [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and 
[on-topic](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) again and if you have questions provide 
your code as [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). If you encounter errors, **copy and paste
the error message verbatim** ( word for word) into your question. Avoid using screenshots unless you 
need to convey layout errors. We can NOT copy and paste your image into our IDEs to fix your code.

Comment: Who are you referring to in your question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be that the playerClass update function uses the pass keyword, which does nothing. If you take out line 28 where you call the playerObject.update() function, the code should run. Or you could add a body to the update function, so that the update function has something to do.